# With Netty, how can you store state per socket connection?

Tags: java, sockets, netty

I'm using Netty to write a simple server application.  It will accept long-running socket connections (i.e. telnet/ssh)... receiving string-based commands and sending string-based responses.

I need to track some session state, about the particular entity on the client end of that socket connection.  I'm unclear on how to go about this.

A channel handler, through the `ChannelHandlerContext` objects passed to its `channelRead(...)` method, can access "attributes".  However, this appears to be for setting state at the **channel handler level**, not the **per socket connection level**.  The Javadocs for `AttributeMap` clearly state:  "*Be aware that it is not be possible [sic] to have multiple keys with the same name*".  Most of the examples out there use this for simple "counter" illustrations.

There was a `ChannelLocal` class in earlier versions of Netty, that might have been relevant.  But it has been removed as of Netty 4.x, and I think that it too was for handler-level state rather than connection-level state.

IS there a way have per-connection state, while still using the `@Sharable` annotation on your channel handler class, and taking full advantage of Netty's non-blocking benefits?  Or is the approach for this use case simply to place instance variables on your channel handler, drop the `@Shareable` annotation, and spawn a new connection handler (and therefore new thread?) for each incoming connection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Channel` does extend `AttributeMap`, so you can just set/get attributes on the channel.
A `Channel` is the abstraction for a socket connection.

On the other hand, there is nothing wrong with creating a `ChannelHandler` per `Channel` and save state in their field. A `ChannelHandler` has nothing to do with threads, those are abstracted by `EventLoop`s and there is only one `EventLoop` per `Channel`.

It is actually the other way round: a `ChannelHandler` is guaranteed to be called by the same thread (the `Channel`'s event loop, or the event loop specified when adding the handler to the `Pipeline`). Thanks to this you do not need either synchronization nor the volatile qualifier for the fields of your channel handler.

Comment: Oh, thank you.  So if I'm following you correctly... I can give my `ServerBootstrap` object's `childHandler(...)` method a `ChannelInitializer` object whose `initChannel(...)` method instantiates a new handler every time?  That handler can lack the `@Shareable` annotation, and store state in member fields?  Nevertheless, although I will be instantiating a new object for each connection... I will NOT be spawning a separate thread?

Comment: In other words, the only real benefit of putting `@Sharable` on your channel handler, and making it a singleton, is reducing the amount of object instantiation?

Comment: Correct! Threads are usually spawned at startup of your application, when you create the `EventLoopGroup` and remain constant until you shutdown the group. It is also good pratice to share the group between multiple netty bootstraps. There is a `ThreadPerChannelEventLoop`, but it is rather an exception than the norm and used only if you want to make blocking IO instead of the usually more performant async IO.

Answer (score 1):

You should annotate your `ChannelHandler` with `@Sharable` then store connection-specific attributes in the `ChannelHandlerContext` using `attr()`. This is very well-explained in [`ChannelHandlerContext` documentation](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerContext.html): "A handler can have more than one context".

Don't use `ThreadPerChannelEventLoop`, it breaks the abstraction over the threading model.